# Razor is replacing ñ character with underscore

Tags: .net, razor

This instruction in razor:

```
@Html.Label("años", "Años")
```

Produces this html:

```
<label for="a_os">Años</label>
```

It doesn't look like a charset issue to me, looks like razor is replacing "ñ" with an underscore when I use it on attributes.

Another example:

```
@Html.DropDownList("compañia", Model.Compañias)
```

Produces this:

```
<select id="compa_ia" name="compañia">
```

So weird and annoying for spanish coding, I am trying to find out how to fix this but I haven't googled the right words yet...

Comment: I don't think it's some kind of problem. More like a decision trying to prevent some issue with browsers that may not support. Anyway, I avoid using special characters in identifiers (Brazilian here).

Comment: But, isn't there a way to change this behavior?
This is an Html 5 private website, so older browsers are a non issue for us.

Comment: Yeah, before HTML5 the `id` attribute was more limited in what it could contain.  http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id   I'm unaware of any way to override this behavior, though.

Comment: Tracing through the source for MVC, it looks like `@Html.Label(...)` ends up calling `TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId(...)` internally.  I see no means by which you can configure this behavior.  Looks like the only solution is to write your own HTML helpers.

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying. Avoiding special characters on identifiers it is then.